# Slowstart Configuration isn't working as expected

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to implement HA Proxy's slowstart configuration. From my understanding HA Proxy will slowly add connections over a set period of time after it is put into rotation. Below is my HA Proxy configuration, only with the pertinent information. `slowstart` currently isn't working as expected. I read the documentation and I might be missing something with the `weight` parameter. However I could not find any examples online. Does anyone see the issue with my configuration?

I do not explicitly set the `inter` value, so it defaults to `2000ms`

Thanks.

```
global
    maxconn 30000

backend https-config
    # Enable sticky sessions
    balance hdr(X-forwarded-For)
    option httpchk GET /InRotation.txt HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ www
    http-check disable-on-404
    http-check expect string IN
    server server1 1.0.0.1:443 check ssl verify none slowstart 7m
    server server2 1.0.0.2:443 check ssl verify none slowstart 7m
    server server3 1.0.0.3:443 check ssl verify none slowstart 7m
    server server4 1.0.0.4:443 check ssl verify none slowstart 7m
```

Comment: The solution was changing the balance hrd(X-forward-For) to balance roundrobin then moving towards cookie based affinity.